# ObjectID.createFromHexString not recognizing inputted hexstring

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am going through Ciaran Jessup's walkthrough of creating a basic blog as an introduction to node.  When i try to view an article, I get the following error:

```
500 Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
at Function.createFromHexString (/Users/me/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:212:11)
at /Users/me/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/articleprovider-mongodb.js:38:64
at /Users/me/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/articleprovider-mongodb.js:16:10
at Db.collection (/Users/me/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:484:44)
at ArticleProvider.getCollection (/Users/me/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/articleprovider-mongodb.js:14:11)
at ArticleProvider.findById (/Users/me/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/articleprovider-mongodb.js:34:10)
at app.post.articleProvider.addCommentToArticle.person (/Users/me/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/app.js:51:19)
at callbacks (/Users/me/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
at param (/Users/matty/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
at param (/Users/matty/Dropbox/projects/node/howtonode_blog/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:132:11)
```

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

From app.js:

```
app.get('/blog/:id', function(req, res) {
  articleProvider.findById(req.param.id, function(error, article) {
    res.render('blog_show.jade',{title: article.title, article: article})
  })
})
```

From articleprovider-mongodb.js:

```
ArticleProvider.prototype.findById = function(id, callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, article_collection) {
      if(error) callback(error);
      else {
        article_collection.findOne(
         // THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION BELOW
          {_id: article_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)}, 
          function(error, result) {
            if(error) callback(error);
            else callback(null, result);
          }
        );
      }
    });
};
```

I have tried to convert the `id` object to a string along with trying to pass it as an object directly.  However, my javascript is pretty bad, and I am having no luck.  I have tried passing `String(id)` and `id + ""` rather than `id` along with:

`{_id: id}`

and

`{_id: article_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID(id)}`

I would really appreciate someone pointing out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for reading!

**EDIT:**  `console.log("req.param.id is " + req.param.id)` outputs "req.param.id is undefined"
The url, `http://localhost:3000/blog/516afb1064036bb345000001`, is correct, though, as I passed 516afb1064036bb345000001 directly to the `ArticleProvider.findById` call and it worked.

**EDIT 2:** It worked when I changed `req.param.id` to `req.params.id`.  However, in my `app.post` function I used the singular `param` as follows and still works:

```
articleProvider.save({
    title: req.param('title'),
    body: req.param('body')
  }  ...
```

Why is it that the singular `param` works here?  Does `params` refer specifically to parameters passed in the URI?

Comment: param is a function for looking up all parameters, params is an object for route keys

Answer (score 7):

without actually showing what `id` is being passed, i would recommend you validate the route. add this:

```
app.get('/blog/:id([0-9a-f]{24})'
```

this will make sure the id passed is always valid.

it's also better just to grab `ObjectID` from the mongodb or bson libraries instead of reaching so many levels.

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

// later
var id = ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id)
```

if these don't work, please show us the actual string being passed via `console.log(req.params.id)`

also, that last callback inside your `findOne()` query is completely unnecessary. in fact, you can just do `collection.findOne(id, callback)`